# How do I flush out previous layers created by leaflet draw tool without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I want to give access to a leaflet draw toolbar via a toggle style menu link so a user can draw one rectangle at a time (actually these will be inserted into a database). What I managed so far is user can toggle on the toolbar, draw a rectangle and when finished toggle off the toolbar, which is fine, but when the user does this a second time (i.e. toggle the toolbar on again) the quantity of rectangles drawn increases. I cant work out why. Can someone explain and offer a solution. The requirement is to generate one rectangle each time the toolbar is enabled.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(map);


var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
            polyline: false,
            circle: false,
            marker: false,
            polygon: false,
            rect: {
                    shapeOptions: {
                            color: 'green'
                    },
            }
    }
});

var step1Enabled = 0;
$('#step1').click(function(){
      if (step1Enabled){
          map.removeControl(drawControl);
          drawnItems.clearLayers();
          step1Enabled = 0;
      }else{
          step1Enabled = 1;
          map.addControl(drawControl);
          map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
                  var type = e.layerType,
                          layer = e.layer;
                  layer.addTo(map);
                  if (type === 'rectangle') {
                      console.log(type, ' drawn');
                  }
          });
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [clear](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-clearlayers) the drawn layers.

```
         // event handler
         function drawCreated(e) {
            var type = e.layerType,
            layer = e.layer;
            layer.addTo(drawnItems);
            console.log(type, ' drawn', layer);
          }

          var step1Enabled = 0;
          $('#step1').click(function(){
                if (step1Enabled){
                    // remove event handler
                    map.off('draw:created', drawCreated);
                    map.removeControl(drawControl);
                    drawnItems.clearLayers();
                    step1Enabled = 0;
                }else{
                    step1Enabled = 1;
                    map.addControl(drawControl);
                    // add event handler
                    map.on('draw:created', drawCreated);
                }
          });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt make any affect. If I toggle the menu item three times when I draw a rectangle I get it drawn three times! Im pulling my hair out.

Comment: Can you give a link to something that shows the problem ?

Comment: I edited the answer. Note the layer.addTo(drawnItems) instead of layer.addTo(map). Is it what you want to do ?

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference. Im sorry if Im not explaining this well. Ive made a fiddle so i hope its easier to see my problem. If you run the fiddle and immediately go to tools and enable the draw toolbar via step 1. Do this again to toggle off, then do it a few more times. When you attempt to draw any shape, the draw:created event fires multiple times. I only want it to fire once, so it should be irrelevant if a user has toggled the toolbar on or off before. Does this makes sense? Use the debugger console to see the log messages printed. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghtynor6/5/

Comment: I think I see what you mean. You have to remove the event handler. I updated the answer. Here is the corrected jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/a4ojwqgr/1/

Comment: Yes that nailed it! I really appreciate your patience and support on this thank you!!